# Facebook React Tutorial: JSX Compiler preventing pollution of global namespace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The facebook react tutorial has the following code and an accompanying note:

```
// tutorial3.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

> Notice how we're mixing HTML tags and components we've built. HTML
>   components are regular React components, just like the ones you
>   define, with one difference. The JSX compiler will automatically
>   rewrite HTML tags to React.createElement(tagName) expressions and
>   leave everything else alone. **This is to prevent the pollution of the
>   global namespace.**

I'm not sure I entirely understand the bolded portion, probably because I'm not as familiar with the internal workings of React yet. My understanding is that the JSX compiler will replace HTML tags as well as my own custom component tags with React.createElement(), but I'm not entirely seeing the connection between how using React.createElement() prevents pollution of the global namespace. Would "h1" otherwise be a global variable or something? How would not replacing HTML tags even work -- I thought React has it's own internal DOM it keeps track of via React.createElement()?

Tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).

Comment: I think its about the window object of the browser.

Comment: This is a good question. I think the idea is that one could pollute the global namespace by introducing global variables for each HTML element - so just like `<SomeComponent />` uses the `SomeComponent` variable in the environment, `<div />` would use the `div` variable. By replacing it with `React.createElement('div')`, there's no need for a separate `div` variable. But this seems almost too obvious of an optimization and so one wonders if they intended more by it.

Comment: @TAGraves That makes sense. The JSX compiler also replaces custom components which is why that part confused me a little, but in that case I'd already have var MyComponent in scope whereas a Div variable wouldn't be in scope, so I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.createClass pollutes the global namespace with custom classes like CommentBox. But, with HTML components, there is no class definition, just a React.createElement.